# Math expressions in spacy

Tags: python, spacy

Using python with spacy (german) to analyse mathematics tasks including mathematical expressions: is it possible to flag these math-expressions? For e.g. with {}:

```
Two cyclists {A} and {B}, {120 miles} apart, approach each other, each pedaling at {10 mph}.
```

Right now (without {}) A and B have different tags (in german: NOUN and X).

Comment: Have you tried the entity recognition? It might flag some of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to do that. First, you should define a new 'math' attribute, indicating that this token has something to do with maths.

After that, you add a new component to spacy pipeline that should achieve the 2 following this:

1. Merge math tokens into one single math token
2. set for this token the math attribute to true

The following code should be fine for your problem:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Token
Token.set_extension('math', default=False)
nlp  = spacy.load('en')

def math_expressions(doc):
    flag_start = False
    to_merge = []
    for index, token in enumerate(doc):
        if (token.text == "{"):
            start = index
            flag_start = True
        if (flag_start and token.text == "}"):
            flag_start = False
            to_merge.append(doc[start:index+1])
    for span in to_merge:
        token = span.merge()
        token._.set('math', True)
    return doc


nlp.add_pipe(math_expressions, after='ner')

doc = nlp('Two cyclists {A} and {B}, {120 miles} apart, approach each other, each pedaling at {10 mph}.')
for token in doc:
    if (token._.math):
        print(token)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works good for me, thanks! The only thing is that I had to switch from "{" to "[[" (and vis a versa for "}"). Unfortunately every squared bracket "[" is recognized as an own token. So I had to set another flag to catch a "[" after a "[".

Comment: Glad it helped you and sorry for the small inconvenience! :)